# Windows (8.1) - How to set an exe as installed program

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Most programs for Windows (I am using 8.1) are in `.exe` format. When you open those files there is a Setup Wizard that has options and extracts files.

However, there are some programs that you download as one exe file, and run it. It creates no other files, to use it you just run the exe (an example and one of the programs I would like to be able to do the following with is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/))

These programs do not come up under Installed Programs as installed, or come up while searching. Is it possible to make them appear as installed programs?

Comment: A program cannot be a .msi file that is just an installer

Comment: Yes, I know that (just worded the question slightly incorrectly), I'll change it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own shortcut to them. EXE files are simply compiled binary files that can be run - whether they run to install an application or are the application themselves. If a program has an installer, it's doing the following steps for you:

1. Place the EXE anywhere you want on your computer (Usually within `C:\Program Files`
2. Create a shortcut to the EXE in the folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

This should allow you to access it through the start menu.

**EDIT:** As recommended below, storing portable apps in the `Program Files` folder may cause confusion further down the line. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/532460/where-to-install-small-programs-without-installers-on-windows) covers some better locations for storing these.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I can access it through the Start Menu, however primarily I wanted to access it via searching with `WinKey + S`, which now also works.

Comment: @Druzion – I do not recommend storing portable EXE files into *Program Files* directory. Months or years later, how would you know whether it was installed with or without installer? For better placement ideas, please refer to http://superuser.com/questions/532460/where-to-install-small-programs-without-installers-on-windows

Comment: @miroxlav - Putting a portable application in a folder called "Program Name Portable" seems pretty clear to me.  Of course most programs can simple be deleted, even a program that uses the registry, can be "uninstalled".  *What a program uninstalls is entirely up to the author of the program.*

Comment: @Ramhound – yes, but from viewpoint of ordinary user, that approach overcomplicates things beyond what is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

The programs that run directly from an .exe file are called portable applications. And unlike Rufus in your case, some create a few files here and there, mostly in the same directory as the .exe file, to save settings in .ini file for instance, but they're still considered portable as they're meant to be run from "portable" drives like pen drives, external HDD, CD/DVDs, etc. without installation.

In short, you cannot make the Operating System view them as installed programs, i.e. they won't appear in Programs list, because they are not and cannot be installed on the system. Hope this is clear enough. Cheers.